# Shouldn't the commenter's name be displayed in timeline?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, timeline

I'm not entirely if this is a bug that has emerged recently or if it's functionality that's always been missing from the question timeline view but at present you can't see who wrote a comment in the timeline view:

[image: Timeline View]

**Whilst in the question view:**

[image: Question View]

It's the fact that the hyphen and date are still displayed that makes me wonder if it's a bug, I can't honestly remember if I've ever seen commenter names on timeline before.  If someone who can remember whether it's ever been there could delete feature-request/bug as appropriate that would be great.

Comment: It's been like this forever. I complained about it somewhere (ah, apparently [in chat, over two years ago](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=236123#236123)), but I guess not in an actual bug report. I think sometimes it *does* show the usernames, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Ah, right, it does show the usernames if the comments are separate events ([example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/105582/timeline)), just not if they're shown attached to the post as in your example.