# Timeline should show user names associated with opening and closing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, timeline

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165593/can-we-add-moderator-features-to-see-keyword-analytics-and-annotated-traffic-gra) was closed, and subsequently reopened. I wanted to follow the sequence of events, so I looked at the [post's timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/165593/timeline), to see if some edit or other action had precipitated the reopening.

I was surprised to see that there are no user names identifying who voted to close and reopen. This seems strange, since that information is easily found from the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/165593/revisions). In other words, I need to look at two places to build a complete picture of the history of a post.

It would be much nicer if the timeline included all the relevant information.

Comment: This lack of usernames is also [evident in the comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164284/shouldnt-the-commenters-name-be-displayed-in-timeline). Perhaps the two are related?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the release of the new timeline, the closed and reopened events will now display the users who voted to close/reopen the question along with the final reason (for closures). Totally random example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/168686/timeline)

Comment: Is the timeline reconsidered and will it be linked anywhere?

Comment: @Palec We've been working on this new timeline for 2-3 years (pretty much since we decided the other one was trash). It's been available to moderators for a long time, and the previous timeline was marked as obsolete and we stopped maintaining it. Rather than completely drop the old timeline, we opted to release the new one to the public. As far as linking it for regular users, still undecided (it is linked for moderators in their mod menu already).

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It's so much better. Also, thanks for keeping the old one alive all along even though it was abandoned... it was somewhat indispensable.

Answer (score 3):

Not that this is a bad idea, but we're not doing any more work on the `/posts/{id}/timeline`.

We consider it something of a failed experiment, which is why it's not directly linked anywhere for normal users.  We might take another whack at the same basic idea later.