# Is it OK for a user with rep below 3K to be able to browse reopen and/or close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

Consider a user who does not have at least 3K rep (such as me right now), which I call a *-3K user*.

#### Scenario 1:

I just browsed the reopen votes for a question of myself. And this is what was shown (user IDs intentionally changed in my question here to `UserX`, X = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, similar for timestamps):

> `User5` reviewed this `I` mins ago: Leave Closed
>
> `User4` reviewed this `J` mins ago: Leave Closed
>
> `User3` reviewed this `X` hours ago: Reopen
>
> `User2` reviewed this `Y` hours ago: Leave Closed
>
> `User1` reviewed this `Z` hours ago: Reopen

Remark: the above tells me that (eg) User3 **voted** to reopen this question, and looking at the consolidated report about all such votes for all those 5 users, is what appears to me like I'm "browsing (a report) about how each user voted (to reopen or to leave closed) as part of this review.". For short, let me call this, in the context of this question, "**`browsing the votes`**" (related to a specific reopen process). Obviously, this kind of votes have nothing to do with upvoting or downvoting posts.

#### Scenario 2:

If I try to browse the reopen votes of another question (not mine), I get similar results.

#### Scenario 3:

If I visit the [history tab on the reopen review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history), all I get is this message:

> You have not reviewed any reopen votes yet.

That must be because I (as a *-3K user*) don't have enough rep for such reviews, so that seems  OK to me.

#### Scenario 4:

Similar experiments about browsing close votes lead to similar access.

#### My question:

Is it OK for a *-3K user* to be able to browse reopen/close votes? Or is this rather to be considered as an *undocumented feature* (aka bug)?

Comment: You cannot see votes. You can only see reviews. That is you wouldn't be able to see votes cast via the links under the question, you can only see stuff done through the review queue, which is always public.

Comment: "I just browsed the reopen votes for a question of myself." Where exactly?

Comment: Sure, It doesn't matter which question, I'm just not sure exactly how you're seeing these votes/reviews (it's not from review since you can't see anything there without the required privilege)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens That's not what Cai was asking. Cai is wondering what path you took to get to the review history for the question (they said "it *doesn't* matter which question", and asked "*where*" and "*how*"). What did you click to get there?

Comment: Yeh, how did you get to the review? (going to e.g. [/review/close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close) without the required privileges just shows you nothing, as you already said in your question)

Comment: You say "If I try to browse the reopen votes of another question (not mine), I get similar results." ...how do you do that?

Comment: I'm asking because it's relevant to this question, not out of curiosity of how one would do it... so it wouldn't really be appropriate for a new question. (I assume you just got the review from the timeline?)

Comment: and as already answered, reviews are meant to be public so I don't think anything is wrong here (you can, for example, [see all my reviews in my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/307988/cai?tab=activity&sort=reviews))

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens No, seriously, we're asking a really simple question that's directly relevant to your concern and is an additional detail about your question that we want to know. It makes absolutely zero sense to me why you'd put forth any argument here or why this is like pulling teeth. Anyways, so you're saying you got to the review history via your profile, correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeline should show user names associated with opening and closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/timeline-should-show-user-names-associated-with-opening-and-closing) <--- this feature was implemented specifically to make details you wonder about not just public (these were public from day one and it's intentional) but easier to access

Answer (score 18):

You are not browsing votes, you are browsing reviews. Reviews are meant to be public. During moderator elections, a link to each candidate's reviews is displayed prominently, so that voters - many of them under 3K - can read through the candidate's reviews.

Comment: You can also just browse any users reviews at any time by going to the activity tab of their profile